# Почему тут ClassCastException?

Tags: javascript, java

```
 Object m1(){        
    return new Object();     
 }

 void m2(){        
    String s = (String) m1();     
 }
```

java dumb question!

Почему тут происходит ClassCastException, если String наследник Object?

Comment: По-моему, все очевидно. Вы пытаетесь преобразовать результат m1 к String, однако m1 возвращает Object. Любой объект String является Object'ом, но не любой Object является String'ом. В частности, ваш Object уж точно не вявляется String'ом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведение вверх по иерархии (все типы являются объектами по умолчанию) возможно, вниз нет.